# Replacing a set object with a new set object

Tags: c++

I have a class with a private field:

```
std::set<std::string> _channelNames;
```

.. and an optional setter function:

```
void setChannelNames(std::set channelNames);
```

In the setter function, how do I replace the private _channelNames field with the one passed from the setter function?

I tried:

```
void Parser::setChannelNames(std::set channelNames) {
    this->_channelNames = channelNames;
}
```

But this produced an error in VS2005:

```
Error   2   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::set' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   parser.cpp 61
```

I am definitely a C++ novice, and expect that I should be doing some pointer work here instead.

Any quick tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Should that be `std::set<std::string>` rather than plain `std::set`?

Comment: Oops good catch. Can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Pass by reference not value `const std::set<std::string>&`, to avoid an extra copy for the value param

Comment: @Steve Townsend: That is the most common advice, but in some cases like this, the code can be as efficient by passing by value and *moving* the copied object, where in this case and with the current standard, *moving* means `_channelNames.swap(channelNames)`. That is not less efficient than the const reference version and might be more efficient if the argument is the result of an rvalue expression (i.e. If you are going to copy at the end, just let the compiler copy for you from the beginning).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to specialize template. You cannot use `std::set` without specialization.

```
void Parser::setChannelNames(const std::set<std::string> & channelNames) {
    this->_channelNames = channelNames;
}
```